# pod document had syntax error while i make install of radius server

Tags: installation, makefile, radius

when i did *sudo make install* in the installation process of freeradius server,
i stucked about this error .

```
installing man1/CA.pl.1
installing man1/asn1parse.1
installing man1/ca.1
installing man1/ciphers.1
installing man1/cms.1
cms.pod around line 457: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 461: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 465: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 470: Expected text after =item, not a number
cms.pod around line 474: Expected text after =item, not a number
POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man line 71.
make: *** [install_docs] Error 255
```

if anyone else  had aware about this,its now time to give remedies to solve this problem

Comment: Which RADIUS server?

Comment: freeradius server which is downloaded from freeradius.org and the version is freeradius-server-2.2.5

Answer (score 0):

That is not an error generated by the FreeRADIUS installation scripts. pod2man is not called by any of the build scripts, and there is no 'install_docs' target.

Comment: how to rectifiy this issue, what i need to do ?. @Arran Cudbard-Bell

Answer (score 0):

This seems not to come from building the Freeradius server itself but seems a common issue with (older?) OpenSSL releases. See e.g. [this FreeBSD forum posting](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/41478/) or [these DuckDuckGo search results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22Expected+text+after+%3Ditem%2C+not+a+number%22+cms.pod).

Additionally [it's unclear why pod2man rejects valid POD syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45573151/pod2man-fails-with-expected-text-not-a-number#comment81716007_45579804).

Update: It seems that pod2man doesn't dislike numbers in general, but dislikes one specific number: Zero. So try to change all cases of `=item 0.` to `=item 1.` and bump potential further `=item <some number>` by adding 1, too. Worked fine for me for fixing the same issue in the POD of Net::IRC.

Answer (score 0):

run

```
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/pod2man
```

then run

```
sudo make install
```

again