# pod2man fails with expected text not a number

Tags: c, openssl, manpage

I am building a legacy version of openSSL to do some testing,
but the build is failing. I have already fixed several things, but now have
got a new one, the log is reporting that it fails when installing
the man pages.

```
        created directory `/Users/AuserName/Documents/proj/folderName/folderNameA/OpenSSL/tt/OpenSSL-for-iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator10.3-i386.sdk/man'
        created directory `/Users/AuserName/Documents/proj/folderName/folderNameA/OpenSSL/tt/OpenSSL-for-iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator10.3-i386.sdk/man/man1'
        created directory `/Users/AuserName/Documents/proj/folderName/folderNameA/OpenSSL/tt/OpenSSL-for-iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator10.3-i386.sdk/man/man3'
        created directory `/Users/AuserName/Documents/proj/folderName/folderNameA/OpenSSL/tt/OpenSSL-for-iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator10.3-i386.sdk/man/man5'
        created directory `/Users/AuserName/Documents/proj/folderName/folderNameA/OpenSSL/tt/OpenSSL-for-iPhone/bin/iPhoneSimulator10.3-i386.sdk/man/man7'
        installing man1/CA.pl.1
        installing man1/asn1parse.1
        installing man1/ca.1
        installing man1/ciphers.1
        installing man1/cms.1
        cms.pod around line 457: Expected text after =item, not a number
        cms.pod around line 461: Expected text after =item, not a number
        cms.pod around line 465: Expected text after =item, not a number
        cms.pod around line 470: Expected text after =item, not a number
        cms.pod around line 474: Expected text after =item, not a number
        POD document had syntax errors at /usr/bin/pod2man5.18 line 72.
```

The pod files contents in the image so you can see the line numbers:
[image]

Comment: Maybe try `make install_sw` to avoid building the man pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"=item" can only be followed by an option string like in this example:

```
=item B<--option>
```

and if you want to pass in values to options, you do something like this:

```
=item B<--option>=I<value>
```

Note that the option string has to be enclosed in B<> and the value string has to be enclosed in I<>.

Comment: Thanks Devin, where can I find some info on pod files, how they work and how to make them. For now I just disabled the documentation for the build.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Wayne You can find some info on pod2man here: https://perldoc.perl.org/pod2man.html

Comment: Thanks Devin. One more question, Does one type the pod files by hand or do you somehow generate them from source files?

Comment: "pod2man is a front-end for Pod::Man, using it to generate *roff input from POD source." from the documentation. Looks like you can generate from the source file.

Comment: From where does come the claim »"=item" can only be followed by an option string« [perldoc perlpod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpod.html) clearly says: »either use "=item *" for all of them, to produce bullets; or use "=item 1.", "=item 2.", etc., to produce numbered lists; or use "=item foo", "=item bar", etc.« IMHO this answer does not explain at all why `=item 1.` causes an error as it is used as officially documented.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `pod2man` doesn't dislike numbers in general, but dislikes one specific number: Zero. So try to change all cases of `=item 0.` to `=item 1.` and bump potential further `=item <some number>` by adding 1, too.

Worked fine for me for fixing the same issue in the POD of Net::IRC.